# It is supposed to give out 6 but I am only receiving 4 as the number of sentences

Tags: python

I'm writing a function `count_sentences` to count the number of sentences in the file:

```
def count_sentences():  
    p = open("www.txt",'r+') #Read mode by default
    content = p.read()
    sentenceCount = 0

    sentenceList = len(content.split(". "))
    print(sentenceList)
count_sentences()
```

This is the contents:

```
**30 years on, what’s next #ForTheWeb?**

**Web Foundation · March 12, 2019**

On the World Wide Web’s 30th birthday, our founder and web inventor Sir Tim Berners-Lee
reflects on how the web has changed our world and what we must do to build a better web that
serves all of humanity. Please share using #Web30 #ForTheWeb.

Today, 30 years on from my original proposal for an information management system, half the
world is online. It’s a moment to celebrate how far we’ve come, but also an opportunity to reflect
on how far we have yet to go.
```

Comment: Why do you expect that the result is 6? The text contains only 4 `.`, so at maximum the result could be 5. But two of the `.` are at the end of a paragraph, so they are not followed by a space.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pay close attention to the actual characters you are trying to count.
For example, not all full stops (`.`) are followed by a litteral space ( ), some have a newline (denoted `\n`, symbolised ⏎), some are not even a full stop :

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.name(".")
'FULL STOP'
>>> unicodedata.name("·")
'MIDDLE DOT'
```

Here is a full solution :

```py
example_text = """\
**30 years on, what’s next #ForTheWeb?**

**Web Foundation · March 12, 2019**

On the World Wide Web’s 30th birthday, our founder and web inventor Sir Tim Berners-Lee
reflects on how the web has changed our world and what we must do to build a better web that
serves all of humanity. Please share using #Web30 #ForTheWeb.

Today, 30 years on from my original proposal for an information management system, half the
world is online. It’s a moment to celebrate how far we’ve come, but also an opportunity to reflect
on how far we have yet to go.
"""


def count_sentences(text):
    count1 = len(text.split(". "))
    print(f"count 1 : {count1}")
    count2 = count1 + text.count(".\n")
    print(f"count 2 : {count2}")
    count3 = count2 + text.count("·")
    print(f"count 3 : {count3}")


count_sentences(example_text)
# count 1 : 3
# count 2 : 5
# count 3 : 6
```